# reveal.js print to pdf only prints the first slide?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, reveal.js

I am trying to use the pdf export option of reveal.js as documented in the [repo readme](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#pdf-export).

I have the following problems:

- I don't see an option for layout (landscape vs portrait) in my chrome print window
- Printing only ever prints the first slide

No idea what I've done wrong or how to troubleshoot it.  I'm using the latest version of reveal.js css etc from Github (sha: 131c00689a4c7a18e5c991fc8102347e4594b5d4) on this [example file](https://github.com/cboettig/sandbox/blob/a9df961c36a039e289ee1d32247b7b6edf95b79d/tex-pandoc-tricks/habits.html).

I'm using Google-chrome Version 34.0.1847.132 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Remove

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="reveal.js/css/print/pdf.css" />
   ```
2. Add

   ```
   <!-- If the query includes 'print-pdf', include the PDF print sheet -->
   <script>
     if( window.location.search.match( /print-pdf/gi ) ) {
       var link = document.createElement( 'link' );
       link.rel = 'stylesheet';
       link.type = 'text/css';
       link.href = 'reveal.js/css/print/pdf.css';
       document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( link );
     }
   </script>
   ```
3. Add `?print-pdf` to the end of URL, e.g. change `.../index.html#` to `.../index.html?print-pdf#`

Comment: The link to the css has to be corrected imho. Currently this seems wrong, just use css/print/pdf.css

Comment: I'm getting a "Removed script tag found in deck" error message when I add this to the HTML via the web UI.

Comment: In one line: document.querySelector("[media=print]").removeAttribute("media") ;)

Comment: Plus one for the ?print-pdf! I've been trying to figure this out for ages and couldn't seem to find it on the reveal website (not saying it's not there, only that I could not find it by searching for "print").

Answer (score 8):

I made a presentation using Slides and exported it in HTML, but for me the William Zhanf solution doesn't work at all. I had all the slides overlayed. This is how I solved:

1. Download the `pdf.css` from [here](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/css/print/pdf.css) and place it in the same folder with the html file.
2. Paste before the `</body>` tag the William Zhanf snippet (with changed path to the css file):

```
<script>
  if( window.location.search.match( /print-pdf/gi ) ) {
    var link = document.createElement( 'link' );
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'pdf.css'; // Notice: I changed the path
    document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( link );
  }
</script>
```

3. Then follow the same instruction: add `?print-pdf` to the end of URL and print as PDF from Chrome.

Comment: I've got exacly the same problem with slides overlay. Your solution works like a charm! :)